# Is there any relation of vqmod with database in opencart 2.1?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod, opencart-module

I installed vqmod in my project on wamp local server, its working fine so i want to upload my work on live server. I want to know is there any relation between vqmod and opencart database after installation. Can any one please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  there is no db relation or tables used by vQmod.  All the xml files are cached to disk as are the modified core files.

Answer (score -1):

Below (Manual install) check the list of file affected files after installation
https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart

Now regarding other files and database, It depends on defined operation of your `.xml` file.